# Twitter Fabric integration in Android app not working

Tags: twitter, twitter-fabric, android-twitter

I use Fabric to do Twitter single sign on for my app as well as use TweetUI to display a Twitter Timeline elsewhere in my android app.

Last night while I was messing around with some stuff, somehow both stopped working. I am getting the following errors:

1) For my single sign on flow: E/Twitter﹕ Authorization completed with an error
com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Authorize failed.

2) For my Tweet timeline activity: E/Twitter﹕ Failed to get app auth token
com.packagewriters.mypackage E/TweetUi﹕ 403 Forbidden
com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: 403 Forbidden

--- This one is weird because Timelines use guest authentication only...so even if I messed up my API keys and what not, this should still work?

I triple checked EVERYTHING and reverted all my changes. I pretty much do everything the Fabric docs tell me to do, not to mention it worked for months before tonight. I'm not sure if I somehow accidentally touched something that messed everything up or if Twitter updated/the authentication servers are down/etc...help please?

Thanks!

Comment: Either my app has been blacklisted or Fabric's auto-generated keys/secrets are not right. I honestly can't think of any other possibility which could make sense given what I've ruled out already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so for Single Sign On, i finally fixed it. You have to go to your fabric.io dashboard and get your key/secret and HARD CODE it into your activity/fragment where you integrate Twitter Log in.

This is weird bc Fabric is supposed to do it for you and I've never had to hard code it in before to get it to work. Something fishy is going on here... hopefully it will get fixed soon.

Tweet Timeline works now. Had to open up the Fabric plugin, navigate to the Embed Tweets subsection and let a gradle sync run its course...

Comment: hi!
i have the same problem....
read your post, make changes (hardcode key and secret), but this doesnot solve my problem...

maybe there some other stuff that you do to fix this?
or maybe you have some ideas about this?

Comment: did you get your secret and your key from your Fabric.io dashboard? Maybe you should press "Regenerate keys" and use those new ones.

Comment: Also you put the hardcoded keys inside your TwitterAuthConfig inside onCreate of whichever activity you implement your Single Sign On

Comment: i am already regenerated all keys, but it does not solve my problem...
can you take a look at my problem?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31280153/error-signin-with-twitter-sdk